# How do you explicitly convert a string to a list. Python

Tags: python

How do I split this string into a list of entities:

`String=('Sues Badge', '£1.70', '3', '13')`

I know that this string may look like a list already, but the program see it as a string. I have tried `String.split(",","")` however this did not work.

Desired Output

`List= [Sues Badge,£1.70,3,13]`

Comment: Your `String` is a tuple, so doesn't have a `split` function - try `list(String)`

Comment: "I know that this string may look like a list already, but the program see it as a string" => what you posted actually looks like a tuple, so what make you say that "the program sees it as a string" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, this is neither a string nor a list, but a tuple, as indicated by the round brackets. `split` is a method of the `str` class, so it can't be used here. To convert a tuple `t` into a list, simply do

```
list_1 = list(t)
```

Comment: This doesn't output `[Sues Badge,£1.70,3,13]`.

Comment: I took the "split this string into a list of entities" as more important than the literal output the OP mentioned in his question, which is missing the quotes around the first list item, because they want to have a list and not something that looks like a list, but is really a string.

Comment: Maybe i got it wrong. I had included an alternate way to the one suggested in your answer.

Comment: which is also entirely correct, if you just look at the desired output. We just focused on different parts of the question that didn't go together :-)

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding the OP just want to see output as `[Sues Badge,£1.70,3,13]`. If i'm right, then the below code will help.

Try this:

```
string = ('Sues Badge', '£1.70', '3', '13') # a tuple
str1 = ",".join(string) # converting tuple into a string
str1 = '[' + str1 + ']' # adds opening and closing square brackets to match your desired output.
print(str1)
```

Output:

```
[Sues Badge,£1.70,3,13]
```

If you were looking for an answer like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53816762/3091398). I have an alternative way. Check this:

```
string = ('Sues Badge', '£1.70', '3', '13') # a tuple
str1 = ",".join(string).split(',') # converting tuple into a string
print(str1)
```

Output:

```
['Sues Badge', '£1.70', '3', '13']
```